# Representing the iterative development of steady state in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, iteration

I would like to use matplotlib to generate a graph similar to this one:

[image: http://imgur.com/Pa254yn]

In my case, I in fact have two equations, one linear, one roughly a rectangular hyperbola, and I would like to show the iterative process by which a steady state of period two evolves.  I can graph the two functions easily, but adding line segments with arrows that demonstrate the oscillation between the curves via the diagonal x=y I cannot figure out, nor how to attach a second y-axis directly below the first that shows the development of the steady-state over time.

The dictionary references are to variables that determine the exact shape of the functions.  I am particularly wondering how to draw line segments as in the below graph, assuming I can generate the necessary coordinates.

Additionally, attaching a second y-axis directly below the first (but perhaps this should be a separate question).

```
def rot_time_series(self):
    fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10), frameon = False)
    ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
    ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)


    x_vals = np.arange(0,100,0.1)
    values = np.empty([len(x_vals), 3])

    for i in range(len(x_vals)):
        y_A = self.mp['cA']['a'] * x_vals[i] + self.mp['cA']['b'] * x_vals[i] / (self.mp['cA']['c'] + x_vals[i])
        y_B = self.mp['cB']['a'] * x_vals[i]
        values[i,0] = x_vals[i]
        values[i, 1] = y_A
        values[i, 2] = y_B

    #mplot.rc('text', usetex=True)
    mplot.rc('font', family='serif')
    ax1.set_xlabel(r'$N_t$')
    ax1.set_ylabel(r'$N_{t+1}$')
    ax1.plot(values[:,0], values[:,0], color="black", linewidth=2, linestyle="-")
    ax1.plot(values[:,0], values[:,1], color="blue", linewidth=2, linestyle="--")
    ax1.plot(values[:,0], values[:,2], color="red", linewidth=2, linestyle="-.")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: As stated, this question is too localized, meaning the answer won't be interesting to other people, and SO isn't a good forum for it.  Here you're asking people to solve a complete math problem for you, rather than answer a programming question.  Any one of these pieces is a good programming question ("drawing arrows on lines", "how to calculate the intercept points", etc), but as a whole it will only doing your work for you, and creating an answer I don't see other people being interested in.

Comment: Do you have any (partially) working code?

Comment: Sorry, I have added code I have written thus far that describes the curves, and refined the question as tom10 suggested.